# Select first unused id using mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have list of ID's in array format as follows

```
$ids = [10, 13, 16, 20, 25, 28, 34, 40, 45];
```

My table record as follows

```
id  email
1   abc@gmail.com
2   xyz@yahoo.com
10  jhs@gmail.com
13  cds@gmail.com
15  gfh@gmail.com
20  dsf@gmail.com
```

I want to compare this table with $ids array and get the first unused id.

For the above example, `I expect the result 16`. I need elegant way/query to find the same.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I use IN, it gives 10. bcoz IN query returns matched rows. am i correct?

Comment: and what about `NOT IN`

Comment: yeah, IN always gives matched results

Comment: @splash58, NOT IN gives 1 bcoz it returns unmatched rows :)

Comment: @Asik reverse not in :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
foreach($ids as $id){
   $result = DB::table($table)->where('id', '=', $id)->get();
   if($result && count($result){
        continue;
   }
   echo 'First unused id :'. $id;
   break;
}
```

?>

Comment: yes, I thought about this already but is there any way through mysql query? thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Say your table name is `emails` and your model is `Email`: use Eloquent to get the *ids*, then get the difference between your `$ids` array and the *ids* from the db, finally pick the first one:

```
$dbIds = Email::lists('id');
$diff = array_diff($ids, $dbIds);
$first = array_shift($diff);
```

Comment: it is very expensive operation in case my table email has more records. am I correct?

Comment: @asik That's right. But adding `where` and fetching record is not difficult. This helps.

Comment: @b0s3, in my case, records will be high. So KTAnj approach is better than this. anyway, thank you Marco. I voted for your quick answer :) and def, it will help someone who is comparing table with less records.

Comment: In @KTAnj approach, you may end doing `count($ids)` queries to the db, and I'm not sure it's faster than using `array_diff()`. But the answer is very simple: *measure it*!

Comment: I measured the two approaches a little, with a 10k rows table with random *id*s and an `$ids` array of 1k items. My approach took about 0.05 seconds, while @TKAnj's one took about 0.001 seconds, so it's faster than mine.

Answer (score 2):

```
create table t1 (id int,  email text);
insert into t1 values
(1,   'abc@gmail.com'),
(2,  'xyz@yahoo.com'),
(10,  'jhs@gmail.com'),
(13,  'cds@gmail.com'),
(15,  'gfh@gmail.com'),
(20,  'dsf@gmail.com');

create  table t2 (id int);
insert into t2 values (10), (13), (16), (20), (25), (28), (34), (40), (45);
select t2.id from t2 where t2.id not in (select id from t1)
```

result

```
16, 25, 28, 34, 40, 45
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/acc36/3)

**UPDATE**

if you say

```
select min(t2.id) from t2 where t2.id not in (select id from t1)
```

you receive only 16 :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   $sql = 'SELECT field WHERE field IN ' . implode( ',', $ids) . ' );';
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    $found = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $found[] = $row['field'];
    }
```

then you can compare with your fields

```
$not_found = array_diff($ids, $found);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if elegant, but you could use a temp table to store your array with used ID's in MySQL. Then you could query that temp table with limit 1 and a NOT IN on the list of ID's that you want to leave out:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_all_ids (`id` INT(11));
INSERT INTO `tmp_all_ids` (`id`) VALUES (2), (5), (3);
SELECT `id` FROM `tmp_used_ids` WHERE `id` NOT IN (SELECT `id` FROM `table_with_used_ids`) LIMIT 1;
```

So build this query in your code by replacing the values in the INSERT INTO with the list of all ID's in $ids, using implode() or something.

Answer (score 0):

You could first get an IDs array from your DB with a

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM tbl_name
```

say you put the content returned in $result, your IDs array would be

```
$db_ids = explode(',', $result);
```

then you can simply

```
$diff = array_diff($ids, $db_ids);
$first_unused_id = min($diff);
```

Answer (score 0):

More performance and optimized code:

```
    // Occupying of unused IDs.
    $used_ids = Dua::pluck('id');
    $prev_id = 0;
    foreach ($used_ids as $used_id) {
      if (1 < ($used_id - $prev_id)) {
        $dua->id = $prev_id + 1;
        break;
      }
      
      $prev_id = $used_id;
    }
```